# How to boot to command-line interface in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, boot, grub, ubuntu-16.04

I want to permanently switch from GUI mode to text mode interface in Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried editing the configuration in /etc/default/grub as follows:

1. Adding `#` before `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash"`
2. Adding "text" in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"`
3. Removing `#` before `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
4. And at last running `update-grub`.

But it didn't work. So what should I do to permanently switch to command line/text interface in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable display-manager service since ubuntu 16.04 moved to systemd.

```
sudo systemctl disable display-manager.service
```

After a reboot it will boot into text mode. Be cautious however, some hardware driver combinations have dead virtual consoles...if that happens, add `nomodeset` into your kernel parameter to boot the system, it will boot with default graphic settings from boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  I think you just want to change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Then, update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Assuming you get that to work , you may want to also remove any window manager and display manager, in which case [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147858/how-to-remove-desktop-environments) could help you.

Comment: Doesn't work! Actually, these things used to work till Ubuntu 14.04 but in later editions (15.10 and 16.04) nothing works.